# Get posts via stored procedure in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, stored-procedures

I have a stored proceduew, which returns a dataset, specific to input parameters.
When I tried to call my procedure from Wordpress, as follows bellow, I have got the error like

*WordPress database error: [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now]*

```
add_filter('posts_request', 'search_posts_request', 2, 10 );

function search_posts_request($posts, $wpquery) {
   return "call my_sp(1, 0)";
}
```

Could you please give me advise (except temporary table solution as a result dataset storage for sp), how to solve this issue and return the data from sp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

1. in wp-config.php add this line to enable mysqli instead of mysql lib:

   ```
   define( 'WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL', false);
   ```
2. in functions.php I updated my code as follows bellow. I added a flag to mark stored procedure call in order to call mysqli_next_result() to clear response buffer as sp returns two results (dataset and result code) instead of one:

   ```
   $sp_called = false;

   add_filter('posts_request', 'search_posts_request', 2, 10 );
   add_filter('found_posts_query', 'search_found_posts_query', 2, 10 );


   function search_posts_request($posts, $wpquery) 
   {
       // mark sql request as a sp call
       $sp_called = true;
       return "call my_sp(1, 0)";
   }

   public function search_found_posts_query($query, $wpquery) 
   {
       global $wpdb, $sp_called;

       if ($sp_called) 
       {
           // clear last response and reset sp call flag
           mysqli_next_result($wpdb->dbh);
           $sp_called = false;
       }

       return $query;
   }
   ```